# should i remove nat gateway after installing database in private subnet?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc, aws-nat-gateway

I am using aws private subnet for hosting database. I have NAT gateway attached to my private route table.It seems very costly.
I don't use NAT gateway for other reason. Should I remove & delete the NAT gateway from my private route table after installing my database in private subnet?

And after removing it can I reattach new NAT gateway in future to my private route table without any problem if necessary.

Comment: Yes, you can remove it if not needed. Then you can create new one if needed again.

Answer (score 2):

A NAT gateway is needed for resources on your private subnets to access the internet.
Note things like S3 access etc will also go over the internet by default. Look at private links if needed.

So if you application/resources don't need access to internet feel feel to remove it.
Do also note that if all subnets are private, you need to think about SSH access if that is needed.

A NAT gateway can be recreated and attached to your VPC without issues.